# How to forward an ansible-awx-credential

Tags: ssh-agent, ansible-awx

The AWX-template is prompting for a credential to connect via `ssh` to a large list of hosts.

This credential should be used to `push` via `ssh` to a git-repository, because i don't want to create or share a ssh-key on every host.

This is possible with `ansible-playbook` in combination with `ssh-agent`.

Is there also a way to use [ForwardAgent](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/agent) with AWX?

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host *
  ForwardAgent yes

$ cat playbook_ssh_forward.yml
---
- name: test ForwardAgent
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: check ssh-key
    shell: ssh-add -lE md5
    register: output

  - name: show usable keys
    debug:
      var: output.stdout
...

$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbook_ssh_forward.yml

PLAY [test ForwardAgent] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [check ssh-key] ***********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [show usable keys] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output.stdout": "2048 MD5:d8:4a:52:41:a7:9e:a3:0d:ff:ff:ff:ff:b5:a3:89:1f rsa-key-20190501 (RSA)"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

AWX returns `"stderr": "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."`

If possible, I need the `ForwardAgent`-Option per AWX-Credential and not changing `ansible.cfg` globally:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=15m -q
```